# Saving Json/txt file with letters 'ąćęśżźół' in Google Drive with googleapis - Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

I am trying to save simple Json file in Google Drive, but during last step I've got an error:
`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (Not a byte value at index 19: 0x17c): Instance of 'CodeUnits'` in row `final response = await driveApi.files.create(driveFile, uploadMedia: media);`

My Json is something like that:
`[{"info":{"name":"Dżejson","weight":35,"address":null,"notes":"some notes"}]`

Login to Google works, saving simple text file works, but saving file with string like Json/text file with letters 'ąćęśżźół' doesn't work

```
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;

drive.DriveApi driveApi = await _getDriveApi();

String contents = await readJson();

final Stream<List<int>> mediaStream = Future.value(contents.codeUnits).asStream().asBroadcastStream();

var media = drive.Media(mediaStream, contents.length);

final response = await driveApi.files.create(driveFile, uploadMedia: media);

...

Future<drive.DriveApi?> _getDriveApi() async {
    final _googleSignIn = signIn.GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [drive.DriveApi.driveFileScope,]); 
    final signIn.GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    //final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final headers = await account?.authHeaders;
    if (headers == null) {
      return null;
    }

    final client = GoogleAuthClient(headers);
    final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(client);
    return driveApi;
}
```

I tried without Polish letter "ż" `[{"info":{"name":"Dzejson","weight":35,"address":null,"notes":"some notes"}]` and it works

Comment: instead `final Stream<List<int>> mediaStream = Future.value(contents.codeUnits).asStream().asBroadcastStream();` try `mediaStream = Stream.value(contents).transform(utf8.encoder)`

Comment: or `Stream.value(utf8.encode(contents))`

Comment: You don't show what `readJson` does. If it just reads from a `File` then use `.openRead()` to obtain a stream. Avoid the whole conversion to a string and back.

Comment: @RichardHeap `readJson();` returns string `[{"info":"name":"Dżejson","weight":35,"address":null,"notes":"some notes"}]`. I replaced it by `String contents = '[{"info":"name":"Dżejson","weight":35,"address":null,"notes":"some notes"},]';`  - with `utf8.encode(contents))` works but `String contents = '[{"info":[{"name":"Dżejson","weight":35,"address":null,"notes":"some notes"},{"name":"Dżejson","weight":35,"address":null,"notes":"some notes"}]}]';` - error `Unhandled Exception: Content size exceeds specified contentLength. 537 bytes written while expected 533`

Comment: Update the question showing the new code (including readJson if possible) and/or ask a new question with updated code and what you've now learnt.